# Ajax don't receives onError Message

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, jquery-mobile

In my aspx login script I don't get server Error messages via Javascript. I don't understand where the problem is or what's wrong.

The script sends an Ajax Response to this URL: `login.aspx?ajax=true` On error it receives a 403 Error Code with Error message. But the Error message could not been found in the data value. Are there some other parameters in VB that I have to send? Or have I made a mistake in the Javascript?

In Firebug I can see the Error message.

HTML

> Login Fail. 3 tries left.

**login.aspx**

```
function onError(data) {
  $('#errormessage').text(this);
  $.mobile.changePage("#loginError", {
    transition: "pop",
    reverse: false,
    changeHash: false
  });
  $("#Submit1").click(function() {
    var formData = $("#loginform").serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "login.aspx",
      cache: false,
      data: formData,
      success: onSuccess,
      error: onError
    });
    return false;
  });
```

**aspx.vb**

```
Catch ex As AccessDeniedException
  Response.StatusCode = 403
  Response.Write(ex.Message)
    'Response.AppendHeader("XML", "<xml><error>" + ex.Message + "</error></xml>")
    'Response.StatusDescription = "<xml><error>" + ex.Message + "</error></xml>"
    'Response.Status = ex.Message
  Response.End()
```

Comment: You got tags, you them instead of the title.

Comment: close the onError function with }

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation

> **error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)Function**
>
> A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP requests. This is an Ajax Event.

So if you want the HTTP status, put the `errorThrown` into the html, or dig it out of the `jqXHR` variable which you `data` variable currently represents.